# Undefined reference adding to existing file and header

Tags: c, mingw, header-files, undefined-reference

first of all I know this is asked a thousand times. But I opened a few and everyone forgot to compile/link it with it.
Anyway I created a linked list in a separate file with header and file, which works fine, however I tried to add a new function to it but then I have undefined reference to 'function.' Here is the source:

list.c

```
#include "list.h"

struct node
{
    item_t x;
    struct node *next;    
};
struct node* root;

//Window hider extension
void ToggleVisibleList(HWND currentHwnd)
{
    if (root == 0)
        return;

    struct node *conductor = root;
    while (conductor != 0)
    {
        HWND hwnd = (HWND)conductor->x;
        ShowWindow(hwnd, IsWindowVisible(hwnd) ? SW_HIDE : SW_SHOW);

        conductor = conductor->next;
    }    

    ShowWindow(currentHwnd, IsWindowVisible(currentHwnd) ? SW_HIDE : SW_SHOW);
}

//...Rest of the file
```

list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

//Window hider extension
void ToggleVisibleList(HWND currentHwnd);

//.. rest of the header
```

main.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#include "list.h"

HWND currentHwnd;

//..

HHOOK hookKeyboard;
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* hookStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
            if (hookStruct->vkCode == 'Z' && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL))
            {
                ToggleVisibleList(currentHwnd);
            }
        }
    }

    CallNextHookEx(hookKeyboard, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

//..Rest of file
```

I compile using Mingw (OS: Windows 8 64-bit):

```
gcc -o hider.exe main.c list.c -mwindows

C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6sCa17.o:main.c:(.text+0x4bc): undefined reference to `ToggleVisibleList'
collect2: ld gaf exit-status 1 terug
//Translation: ld return exit-status 1
```

EDIT: Tried swapping the file order.

I hope I didn't duplicate a question, I don't think so because I've tried 20 questions first. (And google.)
Regards

**Answer: rebooted my computer and it compiled.**

Comment: Looks pretty baffling. Does it work if you just implement "hello, world" using two source files?

Comment: @Potatoswatter Not sure what you exactly mean, I tried a test function that supposed to show a messagebox, but that neither would compile (Undefined reference to 'Test')

Answer (score 0):

Total shot in the dark answer:

I suspect this **might** work (swap list.c and main.c in the compile order)

```
gcc -o hider.exe list.c main.c -mwindows
```

I suggest this because linking with libraries has similar behavior with gcc. But I've never observed this problem with file order.

Fromt the gcc man page (in regards to **-l library**)

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the
>   linker searches and processes
>              libraries and object files in the order they are specified.  Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches library
>              z after file foo.o but before bar.o.  If bar.o refers to functions in z, those functions may not be
>              loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your response, already tried that but didn't work. (I'm sorry should have noted in the main post.) Not really surprising because the other functions in the file are defined/found.

Comment: Have you tried seperate compiles?  "gcc -c main.c -mwindows" followed by "gcc -c list.c -mwindows" finalized by "gcc list.o main.o -o helper.exe -mwindows"

Comment: only other thing to try would be to declare "extern" in your header file for ToggleVisibleWindow. But I've never seen that to be an issue. Did you do a "del *.o" or "rm *.o" before compiling?

Comment: Did everything you suggested but none of it worked. Still getting the undefined reference error. (Even tried moving to another folder.)

Comment: Try #include "list.c" at the top of "main.c" and compile that way. If that still leads to an unresolved reference, then something fishy is going on... like maybe a preprocessor macro replacing part of your code...

Comment: I get multiple definition errors on the working functions in the file, but for ToggleVisibleList I still get undefined reference. That is really weird..

Comment: @iVision Try renaming ToggleVisibleList. LOL

Comment: I remember my first hard lesson with programming in C. I had a variable named "sun".  When compiled on Solaris or SunOS, it would always lead to a compiler error about trying to assign an rvalue to "1". :)

Comment: I rebooted my computer, and now it compiles. Quite weird but I'm glad its working now, thank you for the comments.